# Can we find a pair with given sum and product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

Can we find a pair with given sum and product?

for eg if sum = 5 and product = 6 then the pair will be (2,3)

Is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: Solve the system of equations.

Comment: Do you know how to solve quadratic equations? If yes, do you know what Vieta's formulas are?

Comment: $xy=P \implies y=\frac Px$ and $x+y=S \implies x+ \frac Px = S \implies x^2 - Sx +P=0$ now just solve the quadratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been known since the Babylonians (with other notations!) that the numbers with given sum $s$ and product $p$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$x^2-sx+p=0$$
if the equation has real roots, i.e. if $s^2\ge 4p$.